# searching with date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column named `'tran_date'` that is in varchar.

I have 1 record in the table that is with `tran_date = 12/30/2020`.

When I search with this query using:

```
(SELECT * FROM `financial_transactions` where account_id=1 and 
tran_date>'12/26/2020')
```

it returns a result.

However, when I search with this query:

```
(SELECT * FROM `financial_transactions` where account_id=1 and 
tran_date>'12/26/2020' and tran_date <'01/01/2021')
```

it does not return anything.

`tran_date = '12/30/2020'` is greater than `'12/26/2020'` and less than `'01/01/2021'`.

I am having trouble understanding this.

Comment: You are not searching by date. You are searching strings. This is why you should store dates as dates, not strings.

Comment: Please stop down-voting these types of questions just because the writer is making a clear mistake. The question is clear, answerable with a clear-cut answer, showed the desired result and the actual result

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your own first sentence I'm afraid. Dates should not be stored in that fashion, in a `VARCHAR` type field.
Performing the `<` and `>` operators on a `VARCHAR` type field with the text you have, doesn't work.
Writing a date like 'MM/DD/YYYY' is also a poor choice.

Best thing to do would be to store the date in a field with the `DATE` type field.

Here's a lot more information on said type;
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date/

That being said ...
In case you wish to use the operators `<` and `>` out of convenience, and I can understand why, keep on reading.

Just to test, I've created a test table myself.

```
CREATE TABLE `financial_transactions` (
  `account_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tran_date` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `financial_transactions` (`account_id`, `tran_date`) VALUES
(1, '12/26/2020'),
(1, '12/27/2020'),
(1, '12/25/2020');
COMMIT;
```

Add a new column, which will contain the date in an `INT` field type;

```
ALTER TABLE `financial_transactions` ADD `transDate` INT NOT NULL AFTER `tran_date`;
```

If this column is used more often to perform lookups, add an `INDEX`;

```
ALTER TABLE `financial_transactions` ADD INDEX(`transDate`);
```

Fill the column with information (this query will take your date/time format and add it into the format YYYYMMDD into the new `INT` column);

```
UPDATE `financial_transactions` set `transDate` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(tran_date, 7, 4) , SUBSTRING(tran_date, 1, 2) , SUBSTRING(tran_date, 4, 2));
```

Now, these kind of queries will yield the desired result);

```
SELECT * FROM `financial_transactions` WHERE `transDate` > 20201226;
SELECT * FROM `financial_transactions` WHERE `transDate` > 20201226 AND `transDate` < 20210101;
```

Answer (score -2):

Date should not be store in VARCHAR, You can run this between dates

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM financial_transactions 
    where account_id=1 and cast(NOW() as date) tran_date>'12/26/2020' and tran_date <'01/01/2021'
```